# Fantasy book about a knight that saves a woman in tower

Tags: story-identification

When I was kid, I remember reading a beautifully illustrated book about a man that rescues a maiden who is imprisoned in a tower by an evil knight.  However, I don't remember the title or the complete plot.

What I do remember is that:

- Shortly after starting out on his quest, the knight doing the rescuing is joined by the imprisoned maiden's sister, but the two don't get along at first.
- Along the way, the knight battles several other knights, and has his armor destroyed in the process.
- When he reaches the tower, the knight has to ring a bell to summon the evil knight in order to battle him.  The evil knight's strength changes depending on the time of day, and the rescuing knight was warned not to ring the bell at the wrong time of day.

Does anybody know the title? I have wanted to reread it for some time.

Comment: When were you a kid? You say it was illustrated - was it more of a picture/storybook, or a novel with illustrations interspersed through the book? Did it seem to be geared towards any age group?

Comment: This would have been in the 90s, and it was more of storybook than a novel.  I don't recall it being geared towards any particular age group.